# Yongnuo 85 mm on supposedly-cheap-and-good ef - nex adapter like commlite or viltrox iv

Tags: lens-adapter, yongnuo, sony-a7ii

Is it combo usable, I mean the lens aperture is not dead and focuses accurately on sony a7 i?

Comment: wouldn't it be an EF-FE adapter? (EOS = EF, Sony = FE)

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it's actually Nex mount!